# C source code tokenizer

Tags: c++, c, parsing, tokenize

I'm trying to tokenize a C source code file, and i want to detect the strings and string constatns that are used in that file. So first, i need to match any argument passed as a const char ("text) to the function. Next i need to find all the `char * var[] = "text"`, `char *var="text"` strings. I also need to detect, is those variables are declared on the global scope, or inside a function. I found the FLEX & BISON solution for windows, but it is kinda complicated for the simple task. Is there any pre-written tokenizers for C source code i can use? I tried to do it with regular expressions, but because after the string detection i need to replace the values, sometimes it's going wrong. Plus the  single line `if` `else` without brackets breaks the code after my custom insertions & replacement.

Comment: You need to preprocess the code (this means that you also need to write a preprocessor, or use an existing) ... What are you trying to code (a whole C compiler)?

Comment: I think it is not possible to make a macro that will process the string of any length in compile time.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch no, i'm trying to do some stuff with the strings in the source code file, basically hide some of them. I want to make it kinda universally.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch i do not need the whole complier functionality of course, just tokenizer, so i can detect the function start, `if` `else` blocks start, function calls.

Comment: But you still need to work on the preprocessed form, because some macro invocations can produce string literals, define functions, etc...

Comment: You could customize the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler, perhaps using [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/). But if you only care about literal strings, it is simpler to tokenize the output of some preprocessor (e.g. of `gcc -C -E`). You should edit your question to explain what you want to achieve and what did you try.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch i think i will skip that just for the beginning, basically in the firm we have a lot of code written by the different people, used as plugins for the client applications, and there is a lot of the strings, just laying around "as is" which contain keys, passwords and other important data.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch for example  i have such construction:  `char data [3] = "123";  func(data);` i need to encrypt the `123` first, and replace `123` with the encrypted data, then insert the decryption routine, and copy decrypted data back to the data variable like so  `data [8+3] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03 ... }; char *temp = decrypt(data); strcpy(data,temp);` etc

Comment: please edit your question to improve it. Explain in the question what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

There are some thorns to watch out for:

- Preprocessor macros
- C-Style comments
- String Literals

### Preprocessor Macros

According to the language, you will need to perform a preprocessing step, handling macros.  As other people have commented, macros can produce string literals.

You may not have to rewrite the source (performing textual substitutions), you could store the macro name and its value into a dictionary and reference the value when you encounter the macro name.

That's the easy part.  All the conditional compilation is the difficult part.  Some string literals may not be part of the executable data section because of conditional compilation settings.

### C-Style Comments

You can't do a brute force search for double quotes.  Source code is allowed to have double quotes in a comment, C or C++ style.

C-Style comments are best parsed using a state machine.  And they can span multiple lines.

### String Literals

Remember that string literals may be in other representations than ASCII.

String literals may concatenated, for example:

```
static const char text[] =
  "My Bonnie lies over the ocean,\n"  
  "My Bonnie lies over the sea,\n";
```

String literals may contain double quotes (by escaping):

```
  static const char more_text[] =
    "What does \"MVP\" mean?";
```

So you can't brute force capture everything between double quotes; you need to *parse* the text.

### Summary

Correct and robust searching of string literals in a C or C++ program is more difficult than the simple brute force method of searching for double quotes.  There are syntax rules to the language that make searching by regular expression difficult.  The preferred method is to parse the source file according to the syntax rules.

Rather than writing your own parser or lexer from scratch, you may want use existing open source code or at a minimum, a table for a lexer tool.

Comment: Hello! I used the https://gist.github.com/codebrainz/2933703 pre-written lexer and parser for C99 grammar, but the parser fails with syntax error on the first include, is it possible to get the grammar for c11 for flex bison? Because i heard that gcc is stopped using it as their main parser, so no more lexers are written.